# Mini-GUI to launch remote linux process

Tags: linux, windows-10, shell-script, gui

I would like to know how to develop a script/portable app which launches a Linux process on a remote host.

I have a linux application which runs on its own host.  Everything works on the host.  Most users use Windows 10.  My idea is to start the linux application from Windows 10 and then start up a Windows 10 browser which will connect to linux application serving a web page.

I would like to have a Windows 10 program/script where I can launch and then detach (ideally) that running process.  My Windows knowledge is limited.

A couple of caveats:

1) It would need to be a "portable program/script" that did not need to be installed.  Does Windows 10 have a scripting language or maybe use .net??

2) A GUI would be nice.  Ideally one with a "launch" and a "cancel".  Even better a confirmation textbox once the Linux application has started.

3) The machines DO NOT have WSL and (generally) it can't be added.

I'm looking for high-level guidance on the approach.  Really just the fundamental question of which toolset should I use (Powershell, C#, Go, etc). I can work on coding it up.

Comment: Unless you have an installer, a program doesn't need to be installed. You mentioned Go, and while it's great, has a bad time with GUI's. I reccomend JustBasic (justbasic.com) for easy Windows GUI programming.